# Error creating progressive web app using angular 5

Tags: typescript, angular-cli, progressive-web-apps, angular5

I wanted to create a progressive web application using Angular 5

What I did:

1. Create a new Angular 5 app using the latest version of angular Cli 1.5.3
2. Add the package @angular\service-worker
3. Add a field "serviceWorker": true in angular-cli.json file

4.Build a production build using cli

Problem:

Doesn't work. I get the error. (Please read the screenshot)

Need help to fix this.

[image: Error screenshot]

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgraded the package @angular/service-worker to version 1.0.0-beta.16 and it worked.

**Note**: The versioning of this package is quite confusing. It never had 1.0 released. It went straight from 1.0.0-beta-16 to version 5.